# Modular Inverse of a given Equation

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Am having a problem trying to quickly spot the inverse of any modulo system of equations. This is that i had in mind...

if i for example had $35^{-1}\pmod 3$, the answer if 2. How we arrive to 2 is i thought that $3 \times 11 = 33$ and remainder is 2.

The same method gives me the right answer on 
$21^{-1} \pmod 5 = 1$ and
$15^{-1} \pmod 7 = 1$

but i don't know why $12^{-1} \pmod 5 = 3$. I mean with the same methodology, the answer would be 2. Am i right or something is going on that i dont understand yet?

Comment: Think about the definition of a modular inverse $$b^{-1}b \equiv 1 \pmod n$$

Comment: So that basically means what i was thinking of in the first place was wrong right? or doesnt hold in all situations

Comment: $$2\cdot 12=24 \equiv -1 \pmod 5$$ $$3\cdot 12 = 36 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$ you can figure out what the modular inverse is with the extended euclidean algorithm.

Comment: So in this example, which is the b and how do i manipulate it? Sorry but i dont seem to undestand your methodology is applied. $35^{-1}\pmod 3$

Comment: Oh and by the way, is there a shorter alternative to using the Extended Euc Algorithm?

Comment: You could also use Euler's Theorem. $b$ in that case was $12$, and what do you mean by manipulate it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33790/discussion-between-hakim-marley-and-panphobia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to get the modular multiplicative inverse of some number $b$ in $\pmod n$ you're looking for a $b^{-1}$ that satisfies $$b^{-1}b\equiv 1 \pmod n$$

In your case the reason $12^{-1} \pmod 5 \equiv 3$ is because $$12\cdot 3 = 36 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$
You can only get a modular inverse when $\gcd(b,n)=1$. There are two ways you can get the modular inverse other than guess and check. First is finding solutions to bezouts identity through the extended euclidean algorithm, and the second is eulers theorem.

Comment: So in simple terms, i should look for a number so that when i multiply with lets say 12, i get 1 mod 5 right? Should that be a general rule?

Comment: Yes that is the definition.

Comment: Thank you very much man. It really made a big difference...